# How can I transfer a large file (10+ GB) from HDFS to Google Storage in Java/Scala?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, hdfs, blob

I need to transfer several large files and I occur in error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

or

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

cause I accumulate hdfs file chunks in memory until I get the entire file and then I send it to GS.

I am desperately looking for a way to be able to append data to a blob so that I can only store the buffer in memory and not the entire file.

Looking [Docks](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.html#writer-com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo-com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.BlobWriteOption...-) I found this:

```
 String bucketName = "my-unique-bucket";
 String blobName = "my-blob-name";
 BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, blobName);
 byte[] content = "Hello, World!".getBytes(UTF_8);
 BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
 try (WriteChannel writer = storage.writer(blobInfo)) {
     writer.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(content, 0, content.length));
 } catch (IOException ex) {
   // handle exception
 }
```

But trying to use it I figure out that it only update an existing blob of a fixed dimension and not allow to modify the blob's size. So it is pretty useless for me.

Another condition is to avoid object composition, 'cause I need to store a blob and not a "complex" object for many reasons

Store the HDFS file in local file system is an idea (I can afford it), but remain the problem to upload in GS...

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Check this out: Alpakka project https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/hdfs.html and https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/1.1.0/google-cloud-storage.html

Comment: Try out literally any reactive stream with integrations for HDFS and Google Storage, like Akka Stream with Alpakka integrations mentioned above.